# Elasticsearch single indexing performance

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any difference when indexing elasticsearch by batch data and by single data?
I want to use single indexing, but I don't know it's performance.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk api should be used when ingesting large amounts of data.
There is a significant overhead to pay in terms of resource utilization/performance when using single index api (instead of bulk) to index a large amount of docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using single index would consume time to load the huge amount of logs stored under the index name. If the payload is very high, the performance of elasticsearch would go down drastically, resulting in intermittent unavailability of data loading on the kibana dashboard.

So based on the volume of logs pushed to an index, we should try avoiding single index.